# Shift the complete content to next page if it is not getting adjusted in previous page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a scenario where I have to shift the complete content to next page if it is not getting adjusted to previous page. Currently the content getting broken up between pages. I tried to put the contents inside the frame element but didn't work.

Screenshot:

[image: http://prntscr.com/g6obkz]

And Here is the jrxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.0  -->
<!-- 2017-08-10T12:25:01 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="note11-pledgedassets" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="0" uuid="eff89e48-1135-41dd-b056-b42855f2ba3d">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <style name="style2">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}.equals("Summa ställda säkerheter :")]]></conditionExpression>
            <style fontName="SegoeUI" isItalic="true"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="label" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="amount" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="count" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="number" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="financialYearEndDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="text" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="90" splitType="Prevent">
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="21" y="1" width="530" height="89" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="c171bfff-1a99-40f3-a010-9429cae01a9c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="3.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="3.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="3.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="3.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </box>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="style2" positionType="Float" x="1" y="28" width="364" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="693a615c-58a8-4b74-859f-31da16548c0f">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{amount}!=null && !$F{amount}.equals("0")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <font fontName="SegoeUI" size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="style2" positionType="Float" x="384" y="28" width="100" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="e1094881-70b8-47af-b7d4-a52b16285a12">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{amount}!=null && !$F{amount}.equals("0")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <font fontName="SegoeUI" size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="1" y="15" width="100" height="13" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="82c2a4cc-07ca-4252-99c9-a497c7664c23">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{count}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="1" y="43" width="270" height="31" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="c0fac058-23f1-47e2-a57b-f8d8111437d6">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{text}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <font fontName="SegoeUI" size="9" isItalic="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Säkerheter till förmål för styrelse, vd mfl]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="1" y="74" width="474" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="385ae7d5-4c0e-437e-b04c-64f925c275df">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{text}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <font fontName="SegoeUI" size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{text}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="1" width="490" height="14" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="2dd91d48-f783-422b-9a4c-956f93f62590">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{count}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                </frame>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="2" y="1" width="40" height="14" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="d25eb93c-cf83-449b-8a64-b08b3662dfb7">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{count}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SegoeUI-SemiBold" size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Not]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="384" y="1" width="100" height="14" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="442d41c6-ab53-4af4-a17c-e48f27a60bba">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{count}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SegoeUI-SemiBold" size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{financialYearEndDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="29" y="1" width="40" height="14" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="1b39f3a4-56a6-4b41-af03-01dbed404c68">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{count}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SegoeUI-SemiBold" size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{number}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="69" y="1" width="296" height="14" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="8c1f2b48-7417-494b-9143-08145e05939f">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{count}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SegoeUI-SemiBold" size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Ställda säkerheter]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put that particual content in separate details section and set the split type as prevent for that detail section.